# Intuition behind why a binomial experiment has to have a fixed number trials

Tags: statistics, intuition, binomial-distribution

I'm studying an introductory statistics textbook and it mentioned this:

"There are three characteristics of a binomial experiment:

1. There are a fixed number of trials. Think of trials as repetitions of
   an experiment. The letter *n* denotes the number of trials.
2. etc."

What's the intuition behind the first characteristic?

Comment: In the title, you speak of binomial *distributions*; in the body, you speak of binomial *experiments*. Which do you mean? Whichever it is, you should edit the other.

Comment: It's just a definition.  If you don't want to have a fixed number of trials, you'll have to specify how to know when to stop, and you'll have a different distribution.

Comment: This important part of the definition distinguishes a _binomial_ model from a geometric random model in which trials (of variable number) continue until a Success appears. Also from _negative binomial_ model and a _Poisson_ model,  in which there is again no bound on the value of the associated random variable.